# How to get my saved photos in this file manager in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some issues with my application, I have code that opening camera and saving taked photos but, i can't locate them when i'm using file manager. Can someone help me?

This is, my code to take photos:

```
cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mPhotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createImageFile());
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("A photo", mPhotoUri));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
private File createImageFile() {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "images/");
    if (!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs();
    File image = null;
    try {
        image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

This staff saves photos in: `/data/data/com.example.miarkait/files/images`

And this is code that opening file manager:

```
imageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);

        }
    });
```

But in this manager, i can see only photos taken by "original" camera:
[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2wwe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File(getFilesDir()....

getFilesDir() is your app private storage location.

No other app has access.

Not even file managers.

And you cannot pick it with ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: So, How can I store my photos, somewhere where other applications will see them?

Comment: Put them in your own folder of public directories DCIM or Pictures.